# Whoosh fuzzy matching of the queried word list

Tags: python, search, indexing, fuzzy-search, whoosh

By the fuzzy match here , I mean to find the documents which have like 60-70% of word matches from the word list in query.

Eg :

```
>> #(Query string as passed by user)
>> query =  i am searching for a document that is matched fuzzily with what i am giving here.
>> QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse(query)
```

This query will look for documents with all the words but i want to find all those documents which contain at least 60% or more of the above words.

Since the count of words that I would be dealing with is large and  I do not want programatically partitioning of this word set into different sets (for ORing).

Answer (score 0):

This seems `Not implemented yet` in Whoosh (Checked `28/05/2015`).

However, in the documentation of `[whoosh.query.Or][1]`, there is a reference to a `minmatch` argument:

> class *whoosh.query.Or* (subqueries, boost=1.0, **minmatch=0,** scale=None)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - subqueries – a list of Query objects to search for.
> - boost – a boost factor to apply to the scores of all matching documents.
> - **minmatch** – *not yet implemented*.
> - scale – a scaling factor for a “coordination bonus”. If this value is not None, it should be a floating point number greater than 0 and less than 1. The scores of the matching documents are boosted/penalized based on the number of query terms that matched in the document. This number scales the effect of the bonuses.

If we supposed `minmatch` is the minimal matched keywords so the solution whould be like

```
from math import ceil
from whoosh.query import Or, Term
raw_query = "i am searching for a document that is matched fuzzily with what i am giving here."
min_ratio = ceil(len(raw_query) * 3.0 / 5.0)
query = Or([Term("content", word) for word in raw_query.split()], minmatch = min_ratio)
```

In this case, you should ignore stop filtering or you should filter the stopwords from the query before calculating the length of query.